# Base de datos preguntas por Pais

Tags: phpmyadmin

Tengo una consulta. Armamos una base de datos de preguntas.
Detecta automáticamente el país y ofrece las provincias segun el pais.

Ahora bien,es posible usar las mismas preguntas para distintos paises?
Los paises los tengo en la estructura como varchar(50). Actualmente por cada pregunta solo indico AR o CL por ejemplo.
Si las repito, no se hara muy pesada la bd? Soy principiante en esto.
Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver esto con phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo ideal es que tengas 2 tablas diferentes, una para las *preguntas* y otra para los *países*.

La tabla de países debería contener estos campos:

- id (autonumerico incremental)
- nombre del país

La tabla de las preguntas, por ejemplo:

- pregunta
- id_pais (aquí pondrías el ID de la tabla de países)

Luego para hacer la consulta puedes usar la sentencia `WHERE id_pais IN (...)` y ahí poner los países que quieras.

Si va lento siempre podrías poner un índice en el campo id_pais de la tabla preguntas.

Los conceptos por los que preguntas son muy básicos, así que te paso unos cuantos enlaces para que revises con más detalle:

- https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258743/normalization-in-mysql